# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths without animation

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, animation

I got an app with a `UITTableView`. This table is updatable. And when in the next update the number of rows are less than in previous version, i implement the `UITableView's` method - deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.

I do it in this way:

```
[table beginUpdates];
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[table endUpdates];
```

But when i implement this code there are animations. And this animation is really bad. A lot of black leaks. But i did write - `withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone` in both methods: delete and reload.

Why? How can i reload and delete rows without animation?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the way this is done is by modifying the data source of the table, and calling `reloadData` on the table.

Comment: one more time - i can't do it, because i have first cell, which i should not reload

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me...the table view will just redisplay your cells...is your first cell particularly heavy or something?

Comment: yep. there is gesture recognizer in first cell. if i reload table, this gesture will die

Answer (score 1):

maybe you try to work with NSMutableArray (delete row by removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row) in TableView and reload the whole tableview by using [tableView reloadData] ?

Comment: i can't do it, because i have first cell, which i should not reload

Comment: set the gesture recognizer new in cellforrowatIndex

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make that "gesture" out of the table,and try reload table

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what the name suggests *`*UITableViewRowAnimationNone*`* doesn't help at all.
Maybe setting the alpha on the cell works as suggested here. Not sure though.
[problems with animation when deleting the last row of a TableView in ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976700/problems-with-animation-when-deleting-the-last-row-of-tableview-ios7)